# Undefined variable in laravel (a headache)

Tags: laravel, variables

So i have had a real headache over this issue i have been having. I wish to display posts on my homepage however after refreshing i receive the error message: Undefined variable: posts (View: .... $posts is undefined
Make the variable optional in the blade template.

I have my posts appearing on other pages so i have followed similar process and it should work. However this is not the case and it has been causing me a real headache.

WelcomeController.php

```
public function index()
{
    $posts = Post::all();
    return view('Pages.welcome')->with('posts', $posts);
}
```

Web.php

```
Route::get('/', 'PageController@index');
Route::get('/welcome', 'WelcomeController@index');
Route::get('/services', 'PageController@services');
Route::get('/register', 'PageController@register');
Route::get('/Create', 'PageController@Create');
Route::get('/search', 'PageController@search');
Route::get('/payment', 'PageController@Payment');

Route::resource('posts', 'PostsController');
Route::resource('search', 'SearchController');
Route::resource('reviews', 'ReviewsController');
```

Welcome.blade.php

```
    @if(count($posts) > 1)
@foreach($posts as $post)
  <h2><a href="/posts/{{$post->id}}">{{$post->title}}</a></h2>
@endforeach

@else
   </p>no posts found</p>
@endif
```

If anyone could possibly know whats going on it would be a pleasure, thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try using the PHP function `compact` to send the variable through as a collection.  You are sending using `with`, which is better for flashing data messages:

```
public function index()
{
    $posts = Post::all();
    return view('Pages.welcome', compact('posts'));
}
```

Comment: I am still recieving the same issue, i tried this earlier and it did not work. Really struggling here

Comment: If you `dd($posts)` in your index function, is there actually a value or is it null?

Comment: how do i perform a dd ?

Comment: Right after you assign the variable, execute the dd.  So:  `$posts = Post::all();  dd($posts);`

Comment: i guess i just refresh the page as normal which i did and still receive the same error message ;/

Comment: also i am returning 'posts' to another page called index.blade.php, would this have an effect too

Comment: If you recieved the same error message after adding in the `dd($posts);` before the return statement of your index method, you may be hitting the wrong method - IE you may be routing to a different controller.  If you have the `dd()` in the correct controller, it will not go to the blade page, and not show you the error message.  If it is still going to the blade page, you are likely going to the wrong controller through routing

Comment: i do believe its something with the routing here, i have tried a lot of stuff however i think the routing is somewhat playing me around a bit. i will try and see if i can get this working and let you know

Comment: Hi @Watercayman, i think i may know whats causing the conflict, are you able to create a discussion chat as the problem will be quite complex to discuss

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using another method to pass data to your view, as described in the Laravel Documentation here: https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/blade#displaying-data, together with the PHP `compact()` function

```
$posts = Post::all();
return view('...', compact(['posts']));
```

This will make the `$posts` variable accessible in your blade view.

Also, why not use `$posts->count()` in your view, instead of `count($posts)`? I like the first option better, but I think both work fine.

Comment: same issue still occuring even with this change

Comment: Are you sure you are not using a different route or a different route is triggered? Because this should work. Maybe you can try another variable name or change the route to something random like `/test` to see if it works there?

Comment: now good response, i have changed the variable name and this did not work, however i feel its something with the routing. I will play around with the routing and see whats wrong